# Gmail import contacts functionality in magento frontend

Tags: magento, gmail

How to import gmail contacts in magento frontend?

Comment: First, you'll have to find a library that allow you to do that, and create a Magento module to wrap it in Magento. It's not really a magento related question...

Comment: pretty question how can customize that things in magento ?

Comment: More details on your question would help, it's way to vague.

Answer (score 0):

*No extension is provided yet to get contacts from Gmail*. You can try updating one of the following or build your own to do what you want. They provide functionalities to send mail to Google.

1. [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/specs/1326/aschroder.com-google-apps-email-gmail#specs).
2. [Magento SMTP, Gmail and Google Apps email Magento extension](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/03/magento-smtp-gmail-and-google-apps-email-combined-extension-released-at-last/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no "one stop" solution for this yet.

I've just implemented this functionality for a client project and it wasn't simple. It's probably impossible to release this as a simple Magento extension as it requires lots of customization and configuration that isn't possible as an extension as far as I know. Plus you also have to set up the Google API so I think for a non-developer it would be best to hire someone to do that for them.

The way I solved it is using the Magento SOAP and the Google Contacts API. Some more details can be found here: [Synchronizing Magento with Google Contacts and Gmail (Blog Post)](http://mobweb.ch/2013-11-11-synchronizing-magento-with-google-contacts-and-gmail/).